# Connection refused: PHPUnit selenium in Docker

Tags: php, selenium, docker, phpunit

I'm linking two containers like this (docker-compose.yml):

```
test:
    container_name: test
    image: test
    ports:
      - "7761:80"
    links:
      - webdriver

webdriver:
    container_name: webdriver
    image: webdriver
```

'Test' contains a running symfony website. 'Webdriver' is a custom ubuntu image with the Selenium server running with ChromeDriver on port 4444.

I'm running PHPunit on this file inside the test container:

```php
class SeleniumTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
  public function setUp()
  {
      $this->setHost('webdriver');
      $this->setPort(4444);
      $this->setBrowserUrl('http://localhost:7761');
      $this->setBrowser('chrome');
  }

  protected function login() {
    $this->url('/');

    $content = $this->byTag('body')->text();
    print $content;

    #...do tests...
  }
}
```

Composer:

```
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4",
    "phpunit/phpunit-selenium": "~1"
```

No matter what the value is of BrowserUrl, I can't get a connection. I tried 0.0.0.0, localhost (port 80 and 7761), the id of my container etc.

This is the log:

```
root@/var/www# bin/phpunit tests
PHPUnit 4.5.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

EThis webpage is not available
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
RELOAD
DETAILS

Time: 580 ms, Memory: 3.50Mb

There was 1 error:

1) SeleniumTest::testLogin
PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"subscriptionForm"}
  (Session info: chrome=48.0.2564.97)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371461 (633e689b520b25f3e264a2ede6b74ccc23cb636a),platform=Linux 3.19.0-39-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 12 milliseconds
```

Any ideas?

---

EDIT: fixed using the 3 container plan, see solution below:

PHPUnit:

```php
  public function setUp()
  {
      $this->setHost('webdriver');
      $this->setPort(4444);
      $this->setBrowserUrl('http://website');
      $this->setBrowser('chrome');
  }
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
test:
    container_name: test
    image: test

webdriver:
    container_name: webdriver
    image: webdriver
    links:
      - test:website

webdriver-tests:
    container_name: webdriver-tests
    image: custom-image-with-tests
    links:
       - webdriver
```

The webdriver-tests container can checkout the website code including tests, or a separate test repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a link from your `webdriver` container to `test` one but it would create  circular imports. You may find some workarounds following this link https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/666.

I would suggest separate tests from the main site into another container as they have different responsibilities. Also, this solution allows to avoid circular imports.

Comment: I will look into the link tomorrow, could you elaborate on the different responsibilities bit? You're suggesting using 3 containers?

Comment: Yes, I am! You will have three containers: one which runs php-fpm and main site (it is independent container); another one which provides Selenium server and it depends on 'main' container; and one more container which runs tests and has a link to Selenium server container.